# Why does my multi-touch event not work in my Android Studio App?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, touch-event, multi-touch

Around line 12 of this exempt I have marked a section where the code never gets executed. In the **ACTION_POINTER_DOWN**, everything else works, so if the joystick is pressed the **else if** statement sets **joystick.setIsPressed()** to **true** which sets **joystick.getIsPressed()** to **true** so the first **if** statement should be true, therefore executing code which I marked and also checking the **if** statement above it.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            if (joystick.getIsPressed()) {
                // Joystick was pressed before this event
                if (event.getX() > screenX / 2 && event.getY() > screenY / 2) {
                    cat.isJumping = true;
                }
                // Code here never gets executed
            } else if(joystick.isPressed((double) event.getX(), (double) event.getY())) { // Joystick is pressed in this event and ID stored
                joystickPointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
                joystick.setIsPressed(true);
            } else { // Joystick was not previously, and is not pressed in this event
                if (event.getX() > screenX / 2 && event.getY() > screenY / 2) {
                    cat.isJumping = true;
                }
            }

            if(event.getX() >= mainMenuButton.getValue(1) &&
                    event.getX() <= mainMenuButton.getValue(3) &&
                        event.getY() >= mainMenuButton.getValue(2) &&
                            event.getY() <= mainMenuButton.getValue(4)) {
                isPlaying = false;
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class));
                activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                activity.finish();

            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(joystick.getIsPressed()) {
                joystick.setActuator((double) event.getX(), (double) event.getY());
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            if (joystickPointerId == event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex())) { // Joystick was let go of
                joystick.setIsPressed(false);
                joystick.resetActuator();
            }
            cat.isJumping = false;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's my Joystick.java class for reference:

```
package com.example.combatcats;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import androidx.core.graphics.ColorUtils;


public class Joystick {

private int outerCircleCenterPositionX;
private int outerCircleCenterPositionY;
private int innerCircleCenterPositionX;
private int innerCircleCenterPositionY;
private int outerCircleRadius;
private int innerCircleRadius;
private Paint outerCirclePaint;
private Paint innerCirclePaint;
private double joystickCenterToTouchDistance;
private boolean isPressed;
private double actuatorX;
private double actuatorY;

public Joystick(int centerpositionX, int centerpositionY, int outerCircleRadius, int innerCircleRadius) {

    outerCircleCenterPositionX = centerpositionX;
    outerCircleCenterPositionY = centerpositionY;
    innerCircleCenterPositionX = centerpositionX;
    innerCircleCenterPositionY = centerpositionY;

    this.outerCircleRadius = outerCircleRadius;
    this.innerCircleRadius = innerCircleRadius;

    outerCirclePaint = new Paint();
    outerCirclePaint.setColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(Color.GRAY,125));
    outerCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    innerCirclePaint = new Paint();
    innerCirclePaint.setColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(Color.BLUE,125));
    innerCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);



}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawCircle(
            outerCircleCenterPositionX,
            outerCircleCenterPositionY,
            outerCircleRadius,
            outerCirclePaint
    );

    canvas.drawCircle(
            innerCircleCenterPositionX,
            innerCircleCenterPositionY,
            innerCircleRadius,
            innerCirclePaint
    );
}
public void update() {
    updateInnerCirclePosition();
}

private void updateInnerCirclePosition() {
    innerCircleCenterPositionX = (int) (outerCircleCenterPositionX + actuatorX*outerCircleRadius);
    innerCircleCenterPositionY = (int) (outerCircleCenterPositionY + actuatorY*outerCircleRadius);

}

public boolean isPressed(double touchPositionX, double touchPositionY) {
    joystickCenterToTouchDistance = Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(outerCircleCenterPositionX - touchPositionX, 2) +
            Math.pow(outerCircleCenterPositionY - touchPositionY, 2)
    );
    return joystickCenterToTouchDistance < outerCircleRadius;
}

public void setIsPressed(boolean isPressed) {
    this.isPressed = isPressed;
}

public boolean getIsPressed() {
    return isPressed;
}

public void setActuator(double touchPositionX, double touchPositionY) {
    double deltaX = touchPositionX - outerCircleCenterPositionX;
    double deltaY = touchPositionY - outerCircleCenterPositionY;
    double deltaDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2));

    if(deltaDistance < outerCircleRadius) {
        actuatorX = deltaX/outerCircleRadius;
        actuatorY = deltaY/outerCircleRadius;
    } else {
        actuatorX = deltaX/deltaDistance;
        actuatorY = deltaY/deltaDistance;
    }
}

public void resetActuator() {
    actuatorX = 0.0;
    actuatorY = 0.0;
}

public double getActuatorX() {
    return actuatorX;
}
public double getActuatorY() {
    return actuatorY;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multi-touch works, the event.getX() and event.getY() were the problem.

The solution is to input a pointer id like this:

```
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            if (joystick.getIsPressed()) {
                // Joystick was pressed before this event
                secondPointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
                if (event.getX(secondPointerId) > screenX / 2 && event.getY(secondPointerId) > screenY / 2) {
                    cat.isJumping = true;
                }
```